# Create JSON-array from MySQL-table

Tags: php, mysql, json

Right now I create JSON arraya manually (that means field by field):

```
$cats =     $paed_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC');
$array_cat = array();
while($cat = $cats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $array_cat = array("id" => $cat->id, "content" => $cat->content, "parent" => $cat->parent);
}
echo json_encode($array_cat);
```

Is it possible to create the array in a general way? I mean the tables have different fields (names and number of fields), but this code should work for all tables.

I would like to use that to create multiple array for multiple tables.

Comment: `json_encode($cats->fetchAll())`?

Comment: there is no general way, you need to code it accordingly to what you really want. and by the way, this should be `$array_cat[] =`. this pushes multiple values inside. the one you're using overwrites every iteration

Comment: It is not possible to do that with a foreach loop and key/value or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$array_cat = array();
while($cat = $cats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $array_cat[] = (array) $cat;
}
echo json_encode($array_cat);
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I don't know how many and which fields are in the query. id, content and parent is just an example. Could be something else...

Comment: updated my answer.might help.